# Methods overloading with value and reference parameter types

Tags: c#, overloading

I have the following code :

```
class Calculator
    {
        public int Sum(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }



        public int Sum(out int x, out int y)
        {
            x = y = 10;
            return x + y;
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 10, y = 20;
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

            Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum ( x , y ) );
            Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum ( out x , out y ) );

        }
    }
```

This code work well despite that methods signature are differenciated only be the `out` keyword.

But the following code didn't work :

```
class Calculator
    {

        public int Sum(ref int x, ref int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public int Sum(out int x, out int y)
        {
            x = y = 10;
            return x + y;
        }

    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 10, y = 20;
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

            Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum ( ref x , ref y ) );
            Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum ( out x , out y ) );

        }
    }
```

Why this code didn't work ?
Are keywords like ref and out part of methods signatures?

Comment: `ref` and `out` compile to almost the same thing, so C# doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: For your second code, the compiler gives the following error: Program cannot define overloaded methods that differ only on ref and out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

> Although the ref and out keywords cause different run-time behavior,
>   **they are not considered part of the method signature at compile time.** Therefore, methods cannot be overloaded if the only difference
>   is that one method takes a ref argument and the other takes an out
>   argument.

Also see: [ref (C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/14akc2c7%28v=vs.120%29.aspx))

> Members of a class **can't have signatures that differ only by ref and
>   out.** A compiler error occurs if the only difference between two
>   members of a type is that one of them has a ref parameter and the
>   other has an out parameter.

Comment: If they are not considered part of the method signature, then why does the first example work?

Comment: @DavidS.: That documentation is broken, basically. They *are* considered part of the signature, as my spec quote indicates. It's just that for overloading purposes they're considered to be equivalent in the signature.

Comment: That edit doesn't really answer David's question satisfactorily, IMO. The C# spec is pretty clear that the "kind" of parameter (value, reference, output) *is* part of the signature, but with a restriction for overloading.

Answer (score 9):

To quote slightly differently to the other answers, this is from section 3.6 of the C# 5 specification, which I find rather clearer and more precise than the "reference guide":

> Although `out` and `ref` parameter modifiers are considered part of a signature, members declared in a single type cannot differ in signature solely by ref and out. A compile-time error occurs if two members are declared in the same type with signatures that would be the same if all parameters in both methods with `out` modifiers were changed to `ref` modifiers. For other purposes of signature matching (e.g., hiding or overriding), `ref` and `out` are considered part of the signature and do not match each other. (This restriction is to allow C#  programs to be easily translated to run on the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI), which does not provide a way to define methods that differ solely in `ref` and `out`.)

Note that a parameter type of `dynamic` is slightly similar here - as far as the CLR is concerned, that's just a parameter of type `object`, so this is invalid:

```
void InvalidOverload(object x) {}
void InvalidOverload(dynamic x) {}
```

In that case, however, it's fine for a method with a parameter type of `dynamic` to override one with a parameter type of `object` or vice versa - the important point there is that they're equivalent to *callers*, whereas that isn't true of `out`/`ref`.

Answer (score 1):

This is by specification. According to MSDN page [out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

> Although the ref and out keywords cause different run-time behavior,
>   they are not considered part of the method signature at compile time.
>   Therefore, methods cannot be overloaded if the only difference is that
>   one method takes a ref argument and the other takes an out argument.
>   The following code, for example, will not compile:

Answer (score -1):

it's basically a compilation error as both ref and out are almost same.
both are almost same but a value you pass a **out** parameter need not be initialised.

Comment: No, they're not not "used to send the value type as reference type" - that's a horrible explanation of how it works, and ignores the fact that you can use `ref` and `out` with reference type parameters too. And if the reason is to do with C# treating them differently but the CLR not doing so... if the difference were supported by the CLR, the overloading would be fine.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Thanks Jon, I will correct it, Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: Now it just doesn't really answer the original question correctly. You're saying it's because they're nearly the same - but that could easily be the case and the overload still be valid.