# C# - "You can't overload a method with both a 'ref' and an 'out' parameter (?)"

Tags: c#

Our instructor didn't have an explanation for why you can't overload two methods of the same name one with a 'ref' and the other with an 'out' parameter. Perhaps the great experts at SO can share an enlightening explanation.

Comment: Your question is answered in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729895/methods-overloading-with-value-and-reference-parameter-types.